# After Getting object/array from json, how can i shuffle it (Randomize)

Tags: android, json, random

I got the json data using this

``

```
private void loadQuestions() throws Exception {
        try {
        InputStream questions = this.getBaseContext().getResources()
                .openRawResource(R.raw.questions);
        bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(questions));
        StringBuilder quesString = new StringBuilder();
        String aJsonLine = null;
        while ((aJsonLine = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            quesString.append(aJsonLine);
        }
        Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), quesString.toString());
        JSONObject quesObj = new JSONObject(quesString.toString());
        quesList = quesObj.getJSONArray("Questions");
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),
                "Num Questions " + quesList.length());
        } catch (Exception e){

        } finally {
            try {
                bReader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("", e.getMessage().toString(), e.getCause());
            }
        }
    }

    public static JSONArray getQuesList() {

        return quesList;
    }
```

``

Here is the json data.

``

```
{
  "Questions": [
    {
      "Question": "Which animal is Carnivorous?",
      "CorrectAnswer": 1,
      "Answers": [
        {
          "Answer": "Cow"
        },
        {
          "Answer": "Lion"
        },
        {
          "Answer": "Goat"
        },
        {
          "Answer": "Elephant"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Question": "Humans need",
      "CorrectAnswer": 0,
      "Answers": [
        {
          "Answer": "Oxygen"
        },
        {
          "Answer": "Nitrogen"
        },
        {
          "Answer": "CarbonDioxide"
        },
        {
          "Answer": "Hydrogen"
        }
      ]
    },
        {
      "Question": "Choose the Amphibian ",
      "CorrectAnswer": 0,
      "Answers": [
        {
          "Answer": "Frog"
        },
        {
          "Answer": "Owl"
        },
        {
          "Answer": "Goat"
        },
        {
          "Answer": "Fox"
        }
      ]
    },
         {
      "Question": "---- is part of Earth`s Atmosphere.",
      "CorrectAnswer": 1,
      "Answers": [
        {
          "Answer": "Unisphere"
        },
        {
          "Answer": "Troposphere"
        },
        {
          "Answer": "Oxysphere"
        },
        {
          "Answer": "Carbosphere"
        }
      ]
    },
    ]
}
```

After getting the json data 
All I need now is to randomize it. 
Help a brother please, I have tried everything but nothing is working
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you fix the formatting?

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks Re - Formatted

Answer (score 1):

After 
`quesList = quesObj.getJSONArray("Questions"); // Right place to shuffle PeterOla`,add this to randomize questions list:

```
    List<JSONObject> questionsList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>(quesList.length());
    for(int i=0,size=quesList.length();i<size;++i){
        try {
            questionsList.add(quesList.getJSONObject(i));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    long seed = System.nanoTime();
    Collections.shuffle(questionsList, new Random(seed));
```

Comment: Thanks firesun, I added the code but still not working. Any suggestions please

Comment: After add this code,`questionsList ` has randomized jsonobject,not `quesList` any more.

Comment: Okay. So I added `` return questionsList; ``  to the getQuesList() method. But the app crashes. I know am doing it wrong. Please tell me where am doing it wrong.

Comment: I tried to reach you personally but closest  i got was your github account, and still can't post or comment the code anywhere. So i decided to upload d project here. Please do help me check it out. Thanks https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B__4B3DmNOBtaGtpeXhBOW4yVjQ/view?usp=docslist_api

Comment: I saw your code,and has ran it,no crash existed.
If you want to shuffle your question,I suggest you to declare a `List<JSONObject>` variable named `questionsList `,remove global  `quesList`,like this:
    `static List<JSONObject> questionList;
    public static List<JSONObject> getQuesList() {
     return questionList;
    }`
Then to modify your usage of `getQuesList()`.

Comment: Done that. Thanks a bunch. Except I don't know how to handle the getQuesList(); in the other class, since it's changed from JsonArray to List<JSONObject>

Comment: Replace `QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()` with `QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().size()`,Replace `QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().getJSONObject(qIndex);` with `QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().get(qIndex);` and remove `try,catch` wraps this statement.

Comment: After doing that and removing try catch, i got some  error wanting me to handle exceptions which I did. Then I ran the app but it crashes.  I tried running it by adding the try catch again but still it crashes. Help pls

Answer (score 1):

Put values into a list, then you can shuffle it easily. Use this:

```
    ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();     
    JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray)jsonObject; 
        if (jArray != null) { 
          for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){ 
             listdata.add(jArray.get(i).toString());
          } 
    }
    Collections.shuffle(listdata);
```

Comment: Am sorry, am new to Java, so I don't really get what you want me to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        String current_page = jsonObject.optString("current_page");
        NextPageUrl = jsonObject.optString("next_page_url");
        if (current_page.equals("1")){
            lifeHomeModels.clear();
            JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i =0;i<data.length();i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = data.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = jsonObject1.optString("id");
                String post_user_id = jsonObject1.optString("user_id");
                String post_id = jsonObject1.optString("post_id");
                String post_details = jsonObject1.optString("post_details");
                }

                Family_HomeModel inputModel = new Family_HomeModel();
                inputModel.setId(id);
                inputModel.setPost_user_id(post_user_id);
                inputModel.setPost_id(post_id);
                inputModel.setPost_details(post_details);
            
                lifeHomeModels.add(inputModel);
            }
            long seed = System.nanoTime();
            Collections.shuffle(lifeHomeModels, new Random(seed));
        }
        
        lifeHomeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```